# Time required to check all possible keys (cryptography)

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key

I have found that to determine the time it will take to check all possible keys of a cryptographic key (for example 3DES), it is the multiplication of the key length by the time it takes a computer to try one key. On average it can be guessed after half of the keys have been tried so the result should be multiplied by half.

Now my question is: how do I determine how long it takes a computer to try one key (using the fastest computer)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. I believe such questions have been discussed already on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Thanks for the response. Unfortunately i have been unable to find a response to my question on there.

Comment: This is called brute force. Use 2 ^ (n - 1) where n is the number of *effective* bits in the key. Usually there are faster ways than brute force of course. The fewer shortcuts, the better the cipher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write some code that tries 1,000 keys and run it. If it runs in seconds, then increase the number of keys until you get minutes (or hours, if you are patient.) For example, 10,000 keys, 100,000 keys, etc.

It doesn't matter what keys you try -- you can try the same key of all zeroes again and again. What you are doing is timing a large number of keys in a reasonable time, from which you can extrapolate an estimate of how long it would take to try *every* possible key.